# Additional button in Upload File Form using SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe 3.1.
If i try to upload a file(image) using the File Uploader from CMS and that file already exists, i get the following:
[image]

The thing i want is to **add another button** to "Use That File" instead of overwriting it. I think makes more sense and i tried to search deep in the File class but i could not find where shoud i start.

Answer (score 1):

There is a config setting to tell UploadField NOT to overwrite the file but instead suffix it to avoid name conflicts:

```
$uploadField->getUpload()->setReplaceFile(false);
```

If you want it set globally, you can use config system like:

```
Upload:
  replaceFile: false
```

which is the standard setting.

Comment: i tried your code to set it globally in config.yml, but nothing changed. Anyway, the overwrite button doesn't disturb me. I just want to add another button "Use That File" for instance, to use the file that it's already uploaded, so it will be previewed that one. Thanks anyway